# Giving user a preference to pick either TouchID or Pin login on iOS platform

Tags: user-expectation, ios, users, user-centered-design, authentication

As of iPhone5s we have technology like TouchID which is much secure way of authenticating user instead writing long complicated passwords. Although, we also have a pin login which does require minimal storage inside user brain but it ensures that the authentication must be done with 100% consciousness of the user.

So, I have options to pick and I would like to have pros and cons from community which leads to the best UX.

1. Provide TouchID if touch id is enabled and remove Pin Login preference completely (If the system TouchID is ON then remove Pin Login from app).
2. Provide TouchID and Pin login as two options and let user pick the best fit for them.

I am also looking for more thoughts on how accessibility related challenges we can face between those options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest TouchID should be the primary mode of authentication as it is convenient and easy, But

> pin login preference **should not be removed**

- because there may be the case that his finger might be injured,
- The user might be busy and he wants his task to be done by some other person.

Comment: Although OP asks about iPhone, the Android "unlock" screen (at least for my phone) works this way: default is to use fingerprint, but you can always enter the pin if desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Provide TouchID and Pin login**

- Case 1 : Users hands may get dirty or finger print sensor may have some dirt in this case user prefers to enter pin manually.
  Example: Iphone lock screen/when user's fingers are dirty or sensors aren't working it takes user to enter pin screen / in this case user isn't stuck anywhere , user has a alternative - **always provide alternate**
- Case 2 : User wants someone to operate his phone in this case user cannot come all over to scan his finger it makes life of user harder as there will be no alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

As uttham and Harshith have noted, the pin login functionality should be kept in case of injury or another person using the device but also, many users may not trust/like fingerprint login functionality (though one would think its more secure).

I know a lot of people, mostly above the 18-25 bracket who are less tech savvy and not so keen on using newer technologies, of which finger print scanning is one.